# Passing "Windows key" shortcuts in the guest VM to the host computer with virt-manager

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, keyboard, kvm

I'm using KVM/QEMU on Ubuntu 22.04 and running Windows 10 as a guest VM.  I am using virt-manager to connect to the VM.

I would like all shortcuts that use the "Windows key" to be processed by the host, not the guest.  For example, Win+E should open my text editor in Linux, not the File Explorer in Windows.

But KVM is passing all these key presses to the Windows guest.  This behavior is the same on all the window managers I have tried (Gnome, Sway, and Awesome WM).  For reference, Virtualbox behaves the way I want with respect to the Windows key (but I'm trying to use KVM instead).

Any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  I found a solution: in the host, the environment variable SPICE_NOGRAB should be set to 1.