# super / windows key in virtual machine(qemu/kvm) opens the menu on my host aswell

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, desktop-environment

i've been having this issue ever sinced i switched my Desktop enviroment from gnome to kde,basically whenever i press super it opens the menu on my host as well and its really quite frustating apart from that there are no issues.
pic related:
[image: screencap of my issue]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1652822/register-super-win-key-press-in-qemu

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696746/passing-windows-key-shortcuts-in-the-guest-vm-to-the-host-computer-with-virt-m